# How to create a pull request to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I would like to send a push request to a foreign project where I only have read-access, and open an issue.

I followed several tutorials but I always get the error message that I don't have write-permissions. First, I tried it using GitHub Desktop for Windows, and it didn't work; now I try it directly in the Linux shell.

Here is what I did:

1. git clone https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify.git
2. (Then I change the files I want to change)
3. git checkout -b new_branch
4. git remote add upstream https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify
5. git config user.email "My email address"
6. git config user.name "My name"
7. git commit -S -m "Here I explain my change"
8. git push -u origin new_branch
9. (Now I enter my GitHub login credentials)

And then I get this error message:

> remote: Permission to matthiasmullie/minify.git denied to
> danielmarschall. fatal: unable to access
> 'https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify.git/': The requested URL
> returned error: 403

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to push your changes to your *own* fork of the project, and then create a pull request from there.  GitHub has a "fork" button you can use to create your personal fork of the project.

Comment: You can also use [hub](https://github.com/github/hub) command line tool.

Comment: It is all explained [in the documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/GitHub-Contributing-to-a-Project). As mentioned by others, you first need to fork the repo to which you don't have write access and push to your own fork.

Comment: @prosoitos Does that mean if there if a 1 GB large repository, and I just want to send the maintainer a one-line-fix , I need to fork the 1 GB repository into my GitHub account, just for one line to be reported in a bug report?

Comment: Unfortunately yes... GitHub now makes this easier to do: if you edit a file in someone's repo on GitHub, GitHub will automatically create the fork. But the process remains the same. It has just been sort of automated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the repository https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify.git is the one to which you want to send the pull request. As you mentioned in your question, this will be the `upstream` repository.

You don't have write permissions to `upstream`. Unless you are a very close collaborator of that project, the owner of the repository will not grant you write access to it. So, how do we solve this problem? you want to contribute to a repo but you cannot push to it!

The solution is that you create a copy of that repository **before you follow all the steps you described in your answer**. That copy is called a `fork`. A `fork` is a copy of a repo that belongs to you. It's in your GitHub account, and therefore you have full admin permissions to that copy.

So the first step would be to go to the repository that is owned by Matthias Mullie (https://github.com/matthiasmullie/minify.git) and look for the button to create a `fork` (it's in the top right corner of the screen normally). After you click on that button and wait for some time, you will have a repository that belongs to you The url or that new repository will be [https://github.com/[your-github-username]/minify](https://github.com/%5Byour-github-username%5D/minify) Look carefully at the URL of the fork, It will contain your GitHub username in it, not Mathias'.

Now, you follow the steps that you mentioned above, but using your `fork` as the remote:

- git clone [https://github.com/[your-github-username]/minify](https://github.com/%5Byour-github-username%5D/minify)
- (Then I change the files I want to change)
- git checkout -b new_branch
- git remote add origin [https://github.com/[your-github-username]/minify](https://github.com/%5Byour-github-username%5D/minify)
- git config user.email "My email address"
- git config user.name "My name"
- git commit -S -m "Here I explain my change"
- git push -u origin new_branch
- (Now I enter my GitHub login credentials)

After the last push, you can log in to github.com and you should be able to create the pull request from there.

Please, notice that the name that I used for the remote is `origin`, not `upstream`. The convention is as follows:

- `origin` remote is my `fork`, the one I have permissions to write to.
- `upstream` remote is the original repo, to which I cannot push.

As I mentioned above, this is a convention so you can find other ways to define `upstream` and `origin`